# What should be first: setting or cache object

Tags: php, architecture

I've a very basic question which drives me nuts. I maintain my own little framework. I can configure the framework with a YAML/JSON/XML/whatever settings file. The framework uses also a cache (any of memcached/couchbase/whatever even file based caching if no caching server is installed).

So no I've the following problem: I like to cache my settings parsed from the settings file in the cache but I would like to define the cache type used for that in the settings file.

What would be a proper solution for this? I can't imagine how I should manage this which leeds me to the thought that I probably have a very basic design / architecture error in my framework. Is there any solution at all?

Comment: As everything, the core configuration before anything else, the other includes can depend on that file, which might maintain a majority of the defined constants and other vital settings.

Comment: @DarylGill thx for your comment. But what does this exactly mean to my case? So I should have 2 seprate settings files? One core settings file which never get's cached and parsed over and over again at each request and an application related settings file which gets cached based on the defined cache in the core settings file?

Comment: Load up the core first, then cache.. That's my opinion on the case, others may have a different approach

Answer (score 1):

Well as my experience from Symfony1 and Symfony2 goes, cache as much as you can.

In their production environment everything is cached, so you would run into your problem that the cache type is described in the settings file which is itself cached.

The proper solution to this is: As in Symfony: Delete the cache in prod, once you made changes to settings.

For dev the settings are always re-read as you do not profile in debug, so ease of development is more important that bootstrap time.

I recommend splitting this like symfony did.
For prod your settings are seldomly changed so parsing a file that can be cached is wasted resources and speed is typically priority 1 in prod.

Edit: Your options regarding the order of bootstrapping:

- Always read settings first then decide which cache you will need.
- Use a settings configuration cache that is hard coded (e.g file based)

I recommend using option 2. Your framework is cache agnostic as this can be configured, which is good but for basic settings of your framework you simply do not need that. You don't want to setup different cache mechanisms like memcache, sql etc just for basic settings.

Symfony solves this by the most effective way, as it provides a default cache generation for settings and this is simply a php file. Thats all. When symfony loads settings it looks for a certain  file to include, if it does not exist, symfony caches it by creating plain php and then reads it.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Well the problem's still the same then. When I've cached the settings. How do I know which cache I've to initialize to load the cached settings if the cache configurations are specified in the settings file? So I've to load the settings file anyway again to find out which cache to use...

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I've edited the answer. Was interrupted during answer, sorry.

Comment: Okay sounds like the best option. So basically it's just a `var_export()` stored in a PHP file of the parsed settings file. And include that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the file type from the file extension. Then you can read the cache type and create a cache. The cache should be a singleton.

For the creation of the cache I would use an abstract factory, which implementation is dependent on the file type. The appropriate implementation of the abstract factory then can read the settings file and create the right cache.

Comment: Not every cache is stored in a detectable file. Propbably it's in memcache or redis or couchdb... so there won't be a file a can determine the type of the cache used in my application.